# How to use Pandas Groupby and nlargest

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe `df`, where I am trying to use `groupby` and `nlargest` together but am having trouble getting the output I want:

```
           Date Symbol  Count
0       2013 Q2   AAAA      8
1       2013 Q2   BBBB      3
2       2013 Q2   CCCC      8
3       2013 Q2   DDDD      4
4       2013 Q2   EEEE      5
5       2013 Q3   AAAA     22
6       2013 Q3   BBBB     11
7       2013 Q3   CCCC      3
8       2013 Q3   DDDD     15
9       2013 Q3   EEEE      2
10      2013 Q3   FFFF     10
```

I want to use `groupby` to select by `date`, then get the top 2 `symbols` by `count` for that date, so that the output looks like:

```
           Date Symbol  Count
0       2013 Q2   AAAA      8
2       2013 Q2   CCCC      8
5       2013 Q3   AAAA     22
8       2013 Q3   DDDD     15
```

But when I try `df = df.groupby(['Date'])['Count'].nlargest(2)`, the output looks something like

```
2013 Q2  0   8
         2   8
2013 Q3  5   22
         8   15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Method 1:

We can `sort_values` by `Count` then use `Groupby.head` to get the top 2 rows per group:

```
dfn = df.sort_values('Count', ascending=False).groupby('Date').head(2).sort_index()

      Date Symbol  Count
0  2013 Q2   AAAA      8
2  2013 Q2   CCCC      8
5  2013 Q3   AAAA     22
8  2013 Q3   DDDD     15
```

---

#### Method 2:

Using `apply` with `isin`

```
dfn = df[df.groupby('Date')['Count'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(x.nlargest(2)))]

      Date Symbol  Count
0  2013 Q2   AAAA      8
2  2013 Q2   CCCC      8
5  2013 Q3   AAAA     22
8  2013 Q3   DDDD     15
```

Note: this method will return multiple rows if your top 2 values consist of multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, perform the `groupby` with `nlargest()` and then merge it back:

```
print(df.merge(df.groupby('Date')['Count'].nlargest(2)).drop_duplicates())
```

Output:

```
      Date Symbol  Count
0  2013 Q2      A      8
2  2013 Q2      C      8
4  2013 Q3      A     22
5  2013 Q3      D     15
```

Comment: I get a `ValueError` with that

Comment: That's strange, what is the error? I mean which value, does it say? It ran fine for me.

Comment: It doesn't say which I don't think I've seen before